# Kubernetes dynamic pod provisioning

Tags: kubernetes

I have an app I'm building on Kubernetes which needs to dynamically add and remove worker pods (which can't be known at initial deployment time). These pods are not interchangeable (so increasing the replica count wouldn't make sense). My question is: what is the right way to do this?

One possible solution would be to call the Kubernetes API to dynamically start and stop these worker pods as needed. However, I've heard that this might be a bad way to go since, if those dynamically-created pods are not in a replica set or deployment, then if they die, nothing is around to restart them (I have not yet verified for certain if this is true or not).

Alternatively, I could use the Kubernetes API to dynamically spin up a higher-level abstraction (like a replica set or deployment). Is this a better solution? Or is there some other more preferable alternative?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to accomplish? You mention you need to dynamically add/remove pods but they aren't interchangeable. What does that mean? What's not interchangeable about them?

Comment: @GrantDavidBachman I tried to keep it limited for brevity, but they are not interchangeable because each different pods will be running different packages (which are uploaded by users). There may, for instance, be 3 pods running package A, and 2 pods running package B. If a user removes package B, the 2 pods running package B would need to be removed, and the pods running package A would need to be left untouched.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need [ConfigMaps](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tasks/configure-pod-container/configmap/).

From the official documentation:

> The ConfigMap API resource stores configuration data as key-value
>   pairs. The data can be consumed in pods or provide the configurations
>   for system components such as controllers. ConfigMap is similar to
>   Secrets, but provides a means of working with strings that don’t
>   contain sensitive information. Users and system components alike can
>   store configuration data in ConfigMap.

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) you can find some examples of how to setup it.

Please try it and let me know if that helped.

Comment: I think there may have been a misunderstanding. I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically spin up pods dynamically (or something similar and more correct) - not communicate between them.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I have reconsidered your question and got few options for you. [StatefuSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) alongside [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) with the custom metrics can solve your problem. [Here](https://github.com/luxas/kubeadm-workshop/blob/master/demos/monitoring/sample-metrics-app.yaml) is the example for scaling based on amount of HTTP requests. So you'll need something like:
metricName: java_packageA targetValue: 2

Comment: Also, you can use something like your own [operator](https://itnext.io/building-an-operator-for-kubernetes-with-the-sample-controller-b4204be9ad56). These are things that I have researched. Let me know if you find them useful.